# Is this a secure way to structure a mysql_query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

I have tried and tried to achieve an SQL injection by making custom queries to the server outside of firefox.

Inside the php, all variables are passed into the query in a string like this.

Note, by this stage, $_POST has not been touched.

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO users (password, username) VALUES(' . sha1($_POST['password']) . ',' . $_POST['username'] . '));
```

Is that a secure way to make a change?

Comment: With all due respect. There are millions of people out there smarter then you and me. Who are a lot more malicious. What you have there is an open invite to bring down your site. Just because YOU could not implement a proper SQL injection, does not mean it is not possible.

Comment: using my custom ajax queries in javascript from text encoded in UTF-8 and from within a few browsers (which I realise may encode the data). Is there a best way to test?

Comment: the best is the most visual way. when you can see both input data and resulting query. it is also good to know what are you doing. For example, your data must be stored unencoded. So, what's the matter with browsers encoding? Do you know what way your data being stored - encoded by "some browsers" or not?

Comment: actually, this question should be closed as not a real question. as it can be boiled down to "I passed some unknown data to some unknown code with unknown result"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely escape the username with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Of course the best solution would be to use prepared statements. That way the separation of query syntax and data is made on the mysql API level.

And, as others pointed out, values should absolutely be surrounded with quotes. Especially the text ones.

Comment: i didn't give you the -1 but even if he did run $_POST['username'] though addslashes or msyql_real_escape_string it would still be vulnerable because the variable isn't in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

what you are doing there is dangerous since someone can send a POST request with an evil user name.
you can either check every parameter and escape it,
additionally you could use mysqli (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), 
and bind the parameters using prepare+bind.

the first step is good to avoid exploits on other users,
while the second is good for your server side safety.

also check out this question: [How do you prevent SQL injection in LAMP applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087/how-do-you-prevent-sql-injection-in-lamp-applications)

Comment: why is it that I can't explot it then? I've tried countless attempts of common injections and none produce anything...

Comment: not sure how your PHP is configured, did you try to print the strings? it may already perform some magic on them. if they don't seem like the strings you sent, you may also want to make sure you are sending them properly, they may be encoded this way or another on the client side.

Comment: @Supernovah `$_POST['username']="(select Password from mysql.user limit 1)"`  quote marks are not required to exploit this sql injection vulnerability

Comment: I wouldn't like to supply too many examples, but of course you should also be cautious of html/javascript injection.

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string, adding that to all incomming values should help making it safer.

Answer (score 2):

On checking your code I'm surprised it works at all when you don't quote the literals you are inserting - you will be generating code like:

```
INSERT INTO user (password, username) VALUES (abc1234fg00000, admin);
```

So it will give an error every time. Assuming this is just a typo....

The mysql extension limits your ability to perform injection attacks by only allowing one query per call. Also, there is limited scope for an injection attack on a INSERT statement. Add to that the fact that you change the representation to a neutral format before splicing into the insert statement means that it is not a potential avenue for such an attack. However, your code **should** fall over if someone POSTs a username containing a single quote (if it doesn't then you've got magic_quotes enabled enabled which is deprecated).

OTOH if you apply the same method to validating the account then you are wide open to injection attacks - consider

```
"SELECT 1 
FROM users
WHERE username='" . $_POST['username'] . "'
AND password='" . sha1($_POST['username'] . "';";
```

If $_POST['username'] contains "admin' OR 1 " then your system is compromised.

You should **always** use mysql_real_escape_string() unless you've made the data safe using a different function (e.g. sha1, bas64_encode....but NOT addslashes)

C.

Comment: I can't agree with `sha1, bas64_encode` stuff. all these things has nothing to do with database. you can change your mind and quit use these functions. but query building algorithm should be the same. Better to make it abstract, and independent from  data value.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: but sha1($x)===mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($x)) and base64_encode($x)===mysql_real_escape_string(base64_encode($x)) regardless of what $x is. Note I'm not saying that you should NOT use mysql_real_escape_string() just that it is redundant in some cases.

Comment: No, it is not redundant. Actually I've answered to your comment before, but I'll repeat: Query builder should know nothing of the data. Parametrized queries is a good example: they never ask you if you think it's redundant or not to prepare data. You just do it obligatory. That's the only parametrized queries benefit over traditional way. And good example to follow

Answer (score 1):

this is insecure, unless `magic_quotes_gpc` configuration directive is turned on.
`var_dump(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'));` or `phpinfo();` can show you the actual value

Note that this directive is dirty, deprecated and all-hated. And will make some passwords not work.

Comment: -1 magic_quotes_gpc is very insecure and is being removed in PHP6.  Most importantly **this is still SQL Injection even with magic_quotes_gpc** `$_POST['username']` isn't surrounded by quote marks in the query so you could inject something like `(select Password from mysql.user limit 1)`,  quote marks are not required for exploitation of this query.

Comment: Ahaha @The lamer trying to lecture me again. Just as with MD5, you just run yelling hysterically "very insecure! very insecure!" But in fact you cannot prove no "very" nor even "insecure" with an example you fool. So, do not say what you just heard but never understand. And nobody asked your opinion on surrounding quotes, because they ARE used in the example. Of course it won't work without quotes. That's obvious

Comment: Wow, if you don't see this specific sql injection vulnerability after I have pointed it out then you have bigger problems than just me.

Comment: forget `magic_quotes`, it does not add even a little bit of security …

Comment: @knittl  it does stop *some*  SQL Injection and LFI/RFI attacks,  but agree that by in large its hazardous becuase the programmer should be more aware of the filters that he is putting in place.   A very good example is this sql injection vuln that isn't obvious to everyone,  but if you used parametrized queries it wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder sometimes if they'll find me in the old folks home, screaming "BIND VARIABLES" at the nurses as they walk by.

It's 2010 people, not 1995.

BIND VARIABLES!

BIND VARIABLES!