# Excepted end of statement error in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

When inserting data into a database, the following error occurs

> "Excepted end of statement"

```
 sqlstr = "INSERT INTO tblContact (Email,FirstName,LastName,Comments) VALUES ('" & Email & "', '" & First Name & "','" & Last Name & "','" & Comments & "')"
 objConn.Execute sqlstr
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using single-word identifiers for your first-name and last-name variables:

```
sqlstr = "INSERT INTO tblContact (Email,FirstName,LastName,Comments) " & _
         " VALUES ('" & Email & "', '" & FirstName & "','" & LastName & "','" & Comments & "')"
 objConn.Execute sqlstr
```

**Assuming you've got variables with those names** in your VBScript, that'll solve your current problem with `Expected end of statement`.

Your second problem is your **code's vulnerability to SQL injection**.

To help fix that problem, see:

- [Classic ASP SQL Injection Protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149848/classic-asp-sql-injection-protection)
- http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2008112501&page=1

Comment: I still got error, is any problem in insert query please tell me      sqlstr = "INSERT INTO [tblContact] ([Email],[FirstName],[LastName],[Comments]) VALUES ('" & Email & "', '" & First Name & "','" & Last Name & "','" & Comments & "')"

Comment: @Rameez : Unfortunately, you missed the point entirely. You CANNOT use spaces in your variable names when initializing `sqlstr`. You CANNOT use `First Name`. Modify your code to be `FirstName`.  Secondly, edit your question to show the ENTIRE code, especially where you're initializing `Email`, `FirstName`, `Comments` (where are these values coming from)?

Answer (score 1):

You might have single quote in one of the values, resulting in invalid SQL. You have to escape single quotes, though better rewrite your code to use parameters instead.

```
sqlstr = "INSERT INTO tblContact (Email, FirstName, LastName, Comments) " & _
     " VALUES ('" & Replace(Email, "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(FirstName, "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(LastName, "'", "''") & "', '" & Replace(Comments, "'", "''") & "')"
objConn.Execute sqlstr
```