# How can I make a prepared statement in classic asp that prevents sql injection?

Tags: asp-classic, sql-injection

I have this which works:

```
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE lastname = '" & last_name & "'"
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = dbConn
cmd.CommandText = sqlString
cmd.Prepared = True
Set recs = cmd.Execute
```

The problem I have is that above the dynamic part of `sqlString` is before the prepared statement command.  I don't think what I have above is protecting me.

Don't I have to fix this sqlString before I do the prepared statement?  Reading this made me think that:  [How can prepared statements protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks):

"While in case of prepared statements we don't alter our program, it remains intact
   That's the point.

We are sending program to the server first

```
 $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where id=?");
```

where the data is substituted by some variable called "placeholder"
   and then we're sending the data separately:

```
 $db->execute($data);
```

so, it can't alter our program and do any harm.
   Quite simple - isn't it?"

But I don't know how to make my query correct.  I also don't know how he got from `prepare` to `$data`.  Was hoping for guidance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Why not use ADO command parameters?

```
var oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE lastname = ?";
oCmd.Parameters.Append(oCmd.CreateParameter(undefined,202, 1, 50,"last name"))//adVarWChar
```

Comment: I will try it.  Thanks.  What is undefined,202, 1, 50,?

Comment: oCmd.CreateParameter([name],[type], [direction], [size],[value])

Comment: This would be an excellent place for somebody to link a good tutorial.

Comment: See also [Simple fetch ASP prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259434/simple-fetch-asp-prepared-statement) for VBS example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good blog on how to prevent sql injection using classic asp.

http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/archive/2008/04/28/filtering-sql-injection-from-classic-asp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is using stored procedures in SQL and using Commands that way.. Otherwise, you have to escape out certain characters being gathered from the Request object, like single quotes and double hyphens, etc.