# Why can't I enter a NULL value using Numeric or Date type in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, asp-classic, vbscript, postgresql-9.0

I'm doing a little application for the work and it includes a form. When the person using the form doesn't put a value in a data type "numeric" (lets say a PIN number) or even a date in one of my "date" Data Type fields (lets say his anniverssary), it returns me with the errors as follow:

> *Error Type – Type d'erreur*
>   _Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers (0x80004005)_
>   *ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""; Error while executing the query*
>
> *Error Type – Type d'erreur*
>   _Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers (0x80004005)_
>   *ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"; Error while executing the query*

So it seems that when the person using the form enters nothing, it returns the string "empty" that is "".
Why can't the numeric type and data type read that as a NULL entry? These fields are not mandatory and so I need to have them be sometimes blank.

How can I make it possible? Is their a way to keep using "numeric" and "date" type so that when the user enters nothing in those fields, the table fills with a blank case insted of giving me this error?

Here is my sql statement :

```
trsConn.EXECUTE "INSERT INTO ""TRS"".employeetbl ( "& _
  """firstName"", " & _  
  """lastName"" , " & _  
  """detContract"", " & _  
  "sle, " & _  
  """posNumber"" "& _  
  ") VALUES (" & _  
  "'" & Request.Form("empFirst") & "', " & _**  
  "'" & Replace(Request.Form("empLast"), "'", "`") & "', " & _  
  "'" & Request.Form("dateContract") & "', " & _
  "'" & Request.Form("sle") & "', " & _  
  "'" & Request.Form("posNum") & "');"
```

(The posNum and dateContract are both respectivly of type "numeric" and "date"

Thanks so much for the help. Looking forward for hearing what you geniuses have to say.

Comment: Wow. Does "ASP classic" support *placeholders* or *prepared statements*? I would suspect *one* issue is that it is interpolating the data so it ends up like `.. VALUES (.., 'NULL', ..)` and not `.. VALUES (.., NULL, ..)` as it should be.

Comment: Also, why does `posNum` use `’` (a funny single quote, which is wrong) while the others uses `'` (apostrophe, which is correct)? Can you enter **any** value for `posNum`? (That is, is the title a red herring?)

Comment: This is the classic '"" is not the same as NULL'. NULL is never equal to anything, and you can't substitute anything for it (well, I can't say never - Oracle has been an exception for years). If you want to assign `NULL`, assign `NULL`. If you want to see if a column is `NULL`, use `IS NULL`; they have `IsNull()` and `Coalesce()` specifically to deal with `NULL` values - that's why they have special functions and an operator to check for it. `NULL` <> anything else, and nothing else = `NULL`.

Comment: @pst: I'm pretty sure it is using `''` not `'NULL'` where it should be using just a literal `NULL`.

Comment: @muistooshort That does make sense. Thankfully I've never had to deal with vbscript / "ASP Classic" .. I wonder about the last quotes. :)

Comment: BTW, ASP using the classic SQL drivers DOES support prepared statements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538979/how-can-i-make-a-prepared-statement-in-classic-asp-that-prevents-sql-injection.   Vince, *please* consider using prepared statements, for readability, for the sanity of all around you, and for Poor Bobby Tables http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The concept of NULL in SQL is pretty muddled and inconsistent](http://thoughts.j-davis.com/2009/08/02/what-is-the-deal-with-nulls/) ... but it's very clear that `''` is distinct from `NULL`.

`''` isn't `NULL`, it's `''`, the empty string. You can't convert it to a date, number, etc:

```
regress=# SELECT CAST('' AS DATE);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
LINE 1: SELECT CAST('' AS DATE);
                    ^
regress=# SELECT CAST('' AS NUMERIC);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
LINE 1: SELECT CAST('' AS NUMERIC);
                    ^
```

Some products - notably Microsoft Access and old versions of MySQL - are confused about that matter. `NULL` is NULL, `''` is the empty string; they aren't the same thing. You can't convert one to the other.

> So it seems that when the person using the form enters nothing, it
>   returns the string "empty" that is "". Why can't the numeric type and
>   data type read that as a NULL entry? These fields are not mandatory
>   and so I need to have them be sometimes blank.

That's your application's job. When your app it sees the empty string come in on a form field for a numeric, date, or similar, it should send `NULL` to the database, not `''`. That's normally a routine part of converting data from user input before it's supplied to the database. It is *vital* that you do such conversion; you should never just send values from the user straight to the database.

A quick search suggests that asp classic uses `null` or `undefined` as its null values; you should be able to pass them into your prepared statements when something is null.

The fact that you get a syntax error after the error about `''` suggests that you're building your SQL statements as strings, not using [prepared statements with placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538979/how-can-i-make-a-prepared-statement-in-classic-asp-that-prevents-sql-injection). (Thanks JayC for the SO question ref). This is begging for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection); in other words your application is *critically insecure*. Imagine what happens if the user enters the "date":

```
2012-01-01'); DROP SCHEMA public;--
```

and your app happily turns that into

```
INSERT INTO sometable (blah, blah, blah) VALUES (1, 2, DATE '2012-01-01'); DROP SCHEMA public;--');
```

The `DROP SCHEMA` then merrily executes and whoops, splat, there goes your database. That's just the dumbest, simplest kind of SQL injection attack too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Craig! Everything in that opened my mind, it's really appreciated. Also, I realize that my application is insecure, but it's still in development yet and no one really has access to it but me. It will also not be accessible through Internet since its users will come from Intranet pages of my Agency. Thanks again!

Comment: @Vince.CRA IMO the best time to make it secure it as you write it, right from the start. Security is not an add-on after you're finished, you need to think about it in design, tool selection, right on to deployment if you want to get it vaguely right. As for not being on the Internet - sure the attack surface is lower, but one curious / disgruntled employee (or misconfigured proxy server) is all it takes. There are tools that make exploiting simple SQL injection flaws something *anyone* can do.

Comment: @Vince.CRA Also, seriously, you're developing a *new* application in ASP classic? That's an ... interesting ... decision. How's that going to be to support?