# How can I use an ADODB.CommandObject with ADODB.RecordSet?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, adodb, parameterized

I am trying to make a Classic ASP/VBScript website more secure by making SQL statements parameterized.


I have the following function:

```
Function OpenUpdateableRS(strSQL)
    Dim rs
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open strSQL, cnDZ, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdText
    Set OpenUpdateableRS = rs
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

I intend to convert it to something like:

```
Function SecureOpenUpdateableRS(strSQL, strParam1, strParam2)
    Dim rs
    Dim cmdOB
    Set cmdOB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.CommandObject")
    With cmdOB
        .ActiveConnection = cnDZ
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .Parameters(0).value = strParam1
        .Parameters(0).value = strParam2
    End With
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open cmdOB.Execute, , adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic
    Set SecureOpenUpdateableRS = rs
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

When I call the function with:

```
Set rs = SecureOpenUpdateableRS("SELECT CustID, LastActive, LoggedIn, SessionID FROM tblLogins WHERE EMail = ? AND PWord = ?", strEMail, strPassword)
```

I get a "500 - Internal Server Error" which is probably because I disabled debugging on the server.
Any ideas on how I could make the original function more secure without breaking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create the parameters and append them to the command's parameter collection. Just assigning the values to (the same!) parameter can't possibly work. Google for a sample; perhaps [this VB! sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will get you started.

**Added:**

I can think of two strategies to derive the parameter types:

1. If you pass the *correct/maximally specified* parameter values to the function you can map `VarType(value)` constants to parameter type constants
2. If you do a SELECT based on the fieldnames in the command text, you can map the recordset's field `.Type`s to parameter type constants

It won't be trivial to get this right for all possible cases. I would pass pairs of value and desired type to the function.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is there any way I can use parameterized statements without being sure about the type of the input parameters?

Comment: Like the code on this StackOverflow page:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020846/classic-asp-protection-against-sql-injection