# How to search and display results from an SQL database using HTML & ASP?

Tags: html, sql-server-2005, search, asp-classic

I am currently creating a new database with a web front end. One of the key facilities to this database is the ability to search and bring back result(s). I have setup the database and filled all the tables with information. I have created the view of all the information needed (As instructed by the company I work for). I have setup the page as to how I'd like it to look, here is the code:

```
<!-- #include file="inc.head.asp" -->
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<h1><i>Find User by Name</i></h1>
<div id="displayBox" style="border: 3px solid #9C9595; height: 500px; width: 425px" class="blackBox">

<h2> Search for User </h2>

<form name="Enter New Model" method="Post" action="">

<table>
<tr><td><h3>Name: </td></h3>
<td><input type="text" name="Model" size="50"></td></tr>
<tr><td><h3>Section: </td></h3>
<td><input type="text" name="NextUpgrade" size="50"></td></tr>
<tr><td><h3>Directorate: </td></h3>
<td><input type="text" name="Stock" size="50"></td></tr>
</table>
&nbsp;      
<table>
<textarea name="UserHistory" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea></tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
</body>
<br>
<br>
<h3><a href="page.index.asp">Return Home</a></h3>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

So I want to be able to display the results within the textarea. I will only be used Surname for the search at the moment but have other searches to do, but once I have accomplished this search I can adapt it for the others. Any help you can give me would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have in inc.head.asp? Are you going to process the whole submit on the same page?

Comment: This has links to my style sheets and javascript file. Well I would imagine the code that will perform the search will be on a seperate page and then actioned by the submit.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to figure out some things for yourself in terms of the type of database connection, but the basics are like this (untested):

```
<%
    Dim strUserHistory: strUserHistory = ""
    Dim strModel : Trim(request.form("Model"))
    Dim strNextUpgrade : Trim(request.form("NextUpgrade"))
    Dim strStock : Trim(request.form("Stock"))

    If strModel<>"" OR strNextUpgrade<>"" OR strStock<>"" Then
        Dim strQuery: strQuery = "SELECT Username FROM Users where Model= """ & strModel & """ OR NextUpgrade= """ & strNextUpgrade & """ OR Stock= """ & strStock & """

        Dim objConn: Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Dim DSN: DSN="Driver={SQL Server};Server=DATABASEIP;Database=DATABASENAME;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD"
        objConn.Open(DSN)

        Dim objRS: Set objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL)

        If objRS.EOF Then
             strUserHistory = "No Users found"
        Else
            Do While Not objRS.EOF
                strUserHistory = strUserHistory & objRS.Fields("Username").value & "\n"
                objRS.MoveNext()
            Loop
        End If
    End If
 %>
```

Put this in the top of your page (or make a function out of it) and update your HTML form fields like:

```
<input type="text" name="Model" size="50" value="<%=strModel%>">
<input type="text" name="NextUpgrade" size="50" value="<%=strNextUpgrade %>">
<input type="text" name="Stock" size="50" value="<%=strStock%>">
<textarea name="UserHistory" cols="50" rows="10"><%=strUserHistory %></textarea>
```

Bit of warning that if you expose this to the evil internet you will have to take care of SQL injection and such. A nice [Stackoverflow question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149848/classic-asp-sql-injection-protection) showing all kinds of prevention methods.

But, this should get you started.