# Adding string on one variable in classic asp

Tags: string, asp-classic, character

I'm trying logging verification, everything seems to be fine, but when I add the special characters string to another variable it causes an error to occur.

I'm trying to detect if a user is inputting special characters such as: `!`, `.` etc. something like that.

Here's my code,

```
<form action="" method="get"/>

username:<input type="text" name="user"/><br>
password:<input type="password" name="pass"/><br>

<input type="submit" value="Login">

</form>
```

```vbs
<%

dim user,pass, spchar, getspchar

user=request.querystring("user")
pass=request.querystring("pass")
spchar = "!"

getspchar = spchar

if user = "" then
response.write("Please provide your first name")

elseif pass = "" then
response.write("Please provide your password")

elseif user = spchar or pass = spchar  then
response.write(getspchar &" Special character not allowed")

elseif user <> "admin" or pass <> "admin" then
response.write("Invalid Username or Password")  

else
response.write("welcome")

end if

%>
```

Comment: If you're trying to protect against a SQL injection attack see this question = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149848/classic-asp-sql-injection-protection

Comment: Thanks for that info John. but it's just a plain verification, want to know how to eliminate special character.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is check to see if your special characters are in the list.  Perhaps something like the following...

```vb
<%
Dim user, pass, specchars
'Put all your special characters in the following list...
user = Request.QueryString("user")
pass = Request.QueryString("pass")
specchars = "!£$%^"


If IsValid(user, specchars) And IsValid(pass, specchars) Then
    Response.Write("Username and password are fine! Welcome!")
Else
    Response.Write("Bad username or password.")
End if


'The reason I've given two arguments here is so that you can have different
'restricted characters for both the username and password...
Function IsValid(phrase, special)
    Dim rv, c
    For c = 1 to Len(specchars)
        rv = (Instr(phrase, Mid(special, c, 1)) = 0)
    Next
    IsValid = rv
End Function
%>
```

Just as an aside, here, you're visually displaying your username and password in the query string which is tagged on to the end of your URL (something like `www.example.com/default.asp?user=admin&pass=G0d`); this isn't a good idea. Try at least using `POST` in your form instead of `GET`. If you do this, then you're going to have to look at changing to using `Request.Form("controlname")` ... and that's just scratching the surface.

Please remember that this is a very basic piece of code and I would not recommend using any structure like this for your security on the internet. You'll need to look into Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and similar encryption.

Comment: Could also do this with a `RegExp` object, not benchmarked it though.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I'll take note to that.